# Query SQLite database file size?

Tags: linux, sqlite

We're building a sensor-data-collecting linux application for a small ARM device, the data get stored in an SQLite database on an SD-card. Because of the limited resources I want to periodically check the (physical) DB size and drop old data every once in a while.

I could use C++ or OS functions to get the file size, but I think it would be way more elegant and portable if I could get the file size directly from the DB by querying it. Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

Dropping data does not reduce the file size (the free pages just stay in the database file, and can be reused for new data).

Reducing the database file size is done by executing [VACUUM](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_vacuum.html), but that actually require three times the file size to copy around the file.

There is no mechanism to query the file size; you have to use some OS function. But to find out how many free pages there are, use [PRAGMA freelist_count](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_freelist_count).

To prevent the database from becoming too large, use [PRAGMA max_page_count](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_max_page_count) (and be prepared to handle the resulting errors).